# How to compare a string array to user input to see if correct

Tags: java

this is basically the same thing i got to compare numbers from user input, with "int", but for some reason it doesnt work for words in an array of strings even when it is correct. its unfinished, i just want to make it compare properly.

```
            case 2:

            cell = (int)((Math.random() * 59) + 1);
            System.out.println(englishNumbers[cell]);
            System.out.println("what is the number? >");
            String w = in.nextLine();
            if(w != frenchNumbers[cell])
            {
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
                numChoice(2);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("That's correct");
                numChoice(2);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: i dont see how this is a duplicate from the given example. this is from user input not from 2 strings that are already defined. this compares input to one defined string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if(!w.equals(frenchNumbers[cell]))`

instead of

`if(w != frenchNumbers[cell])`.

You must compare values, not references.